# How do I craft glowstone in the PS3 edition of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

After collecting some glowstone dust, I trodded on home to create some glowstone. Opened up my trusty crafting table and began to look for glowstone. To my dismay, I couldn't find it right away.

If I could, I would just lay out the recipe and build what I need.

[image: glowstone]

The PS3 only has a recipe list though. Where is the recipe for glowstone in the PS3 version of Minecraft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's under tools in the torch section (light, yo!).

As it turns out, the PS3 version works just like the Xbox version. If you find help with something on the Xbox, it probably applies to the PS3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

They're under tools, in the drop down on the torches